# PC to MAC Ethernet LAN

Tags: windows-xp, mac-osx, local-area-network, vnc

I'm trying to setup VNC between a (Windows XP) PC and a MAC (OS X) for semi-permanent installation in a space, but I can't even get the PC to ping the mac. I've got an ethernet cable running between my PC and my Mac, firewall is disabled on the PC. Is there some windows setting that would block outgoing TCP connections? Static IP addresses are set on both machines. (This system will never be connected to the internet so no worries on security). I intend to use Vineserver and RealVNC once I get around this issue.

Comment: Post the output of `ipconfig` from the PC and `ifconfig` from the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I had the two machines on different subnet masks, they are now connecting.

Comment: Thanks for posting your resolution. Please accept your own answer to close this question.